# Understanding MVC & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am following some tutorials and I'm completely lost on how MVC/SQL Server connect.

I am going through a tutorial and the person mentions that the following code automatically creates a database for me:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="LibraryContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source = |DataDirectory|Library.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

Can you please tell me what the above code does in a simple and detailed way. What `|DataDirectory|Library.sdf` does and what SQL Server CE..etc...all of it.. PLEASE & THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SQL Server CE is the **Compact Edition** of SQL Server - basically your whole database in a single file (the `.sdf` file) and the code to access it in a set of DLLs - no server installation needed.

  It works fine for most cases, but has limitations (no stored procedures etc.) - [ErikEJ has a great comparison page comparing SQL Server CE to Express](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html)
- the `|DataDirectory|` part of your connection string refers to the `App_Data` directory that's been created in your web site

  So in the end, the database connection goes to a file in

  ```
  (your web site root)\App_Data\Library.sdf
  ```

Answer (score 2):

MVC is effectively a tiered presentation layer - it can act alone, or with any back end database.

The "code" you have posted above is not code - it's configuration information that's read from a configuration file (in your case, web.config). Configuration files are used to store and easily change settings in your applications.

A connection string is literally just a string that contains database credentials. The database would need to already exist somewhere (unless you decide to implement a code-first ORM like Entity Framework code-first). In your example, you're trying to connect to an existing SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) file. You would need to create a SQL Server CE file in your App_Data directory. I'm afraid I only use the full "server" version of SQL Server, so I can't help you there, unless I look it up!

Once your database exists, you can connect to it in a lot of different ways. My current preference is Entity Framework, though historically it's been via ADO.Net. I would Google "Hello World SQL Server", which should help you find a decent tutorial on where to start.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can connect to a proper SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I have made a simple database in there using SQL servers IDE. I have an mvc application and I'm just thinking how to link them together. What's the best way? I keep hearing about linq/entity framework etc.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. Even though EF is quicker and easier, I would recommend learning some ADO.Net so you can hopefully appreciate where EF comes from. There are a lot of examples on here.